# How to VPN to Amazon AWS Network

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services

Forgive me if this question does not make total sense as I am knew to the concepts of networking.

Basically I have an EC2 instance set up on AWS and I am wondering if somehow I can get VPN access into the network (or the subnet) where my EC2 instance is.

My hope would be that I could directly connect to it using a local IP, or to VNC into it with a local IP address.

I want to do this so that I can see the computer (and all its drives information) from my Mac laptop or Windows box.

Is it possible to configure this?

Comment: You could run a VPN on the EC2 instance itself.  Your EC2 instance isn't going to have a local IP though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ramhound mentioned you could run a VPN server on the instance itself but since it sounds like you do not have much experience doing this I recommend using the OpenVPN appliance that is available in the AWS Marketplace. Here is a great tutorial to teach you how to set it up and connect:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWqRrMGHJQg

Here is the OpenVPN for AWS Quick Start guide as well:

https://docs.openvpn.net/how-to-tutorialsguides/virtual-platforms/amazon-ec2-appliance-ami-quick-start-guide/

If you successfully setup the OpenVPN server and your client PC, once you are connected over the OpenVPN you should be able to ping the AWS OpenVPN instance's private IP from your client PC. There are other ways to connect via VPN but the OpenVPN method is probably the easiest in my opinion.

Note that this will get your VPN up and running; how you intend on mapping drives might be a different question / topic.

Comment: I was looking for a way to setup a vpn on an already existing machine.  It appears that this requires an AMI (which would requitre setting up a new server).

Comment: Please let us know the specific type of EC2 instance you want to install the VPN server on.

Comment: If you are using a Linux instance then here are the steps to get started with install the OpenVPN access server on your existing instance: https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/quick-start-guide.html